# Simplest definition for graph genus?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm trying to understand the graph genus. I've read some defs, but I still find confusing, how the genus can be reliably counted.

Simplest definition for graph genus?

---

How about:

Smallest number of holes in the graph possible so that it can be "laid on" a surface of equivalent number of holes?

Comment: Please add a source (or more than one) for the definition of "graph genus" you are trying to understand.  I would suspect that definitions of authors may vary because of trade-offs in proving equivalent characterizations.  Already with planar graphs we have some nice algorithms (re: "reliably counted").